# Why is this JavaScript gallery not being copied properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I downloaded a gallery from [tympanus.net](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BubblerifficImageGallery/) and then I've uploaded the gallery [here](http://outboxvision.com/BubblerifficImageGallery/).

It's exactly the same code; why is it not showing the same gallery?

Comment: Look at your console and you will know why.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the images. Its trying to load them from the wrong location. Try changing the location to the correct one and voila your ready to go.